# When do instantiate a reference vs the object itself in C++?

Tags: c++

```
auto& myOBj_ref = MyClass();

vs

auto myObj = MyClass()
```

I'm not talking about passing a parameter to a function, but inside a function itself, what are the usual use cases for instantiate a reference to an instance vs just the object itself?

Comment: Are you talking about having an alias for `this` so instead of `this->something` you can do `self.something`?

Comment: The first one simply doesn't compile, so this is a bit of a confusing question.

Comment: What is `MyClass`? Should we assume it is a type (so `MyClass()` creates a temporary via the default constructor), instead of a function that returns a specific instance of a type named `Class` (a confusing name, but allowed given the capitalization)? A function that returns a reference would involve different considerations than constructing a temporary object.

Comment: @JaMiT MyClass() is the default constructor that returns an instance in this example.

Comment: @user1008636 Consider adding the line `class MyClass {};` to your code block so that this is clear. Or adding more text to explain what you mean.

Answer (score 5):

> ```
> auto myOBj_ref& = MyClass();
> ```

This is syntactically wrong, so the program is ill-formed.

```
auto& myOBj_ref = MyClass();
```

This is also ill-formed, because a prvalue such as the temporary object cannot be bound to an lvalue reference to non-const.

```
const auto& myOBj_ref = MyClass();

auto&& myOBj_ref = MyClass();
```

Although these work, there's no point in using lifetime extension this way.

> ```
> auto myObj = MyClass();
> ```

Use this. Or, you can also use:

```
MyClass myObj{};
```

> what are the usual use cases for instantiate a reference to an instance vs just the object itself?

The usual case for using lifetime extension of object bound to a reference is where the object is a reference wrapper (or similar), and it is used in a template where it might in other case be a reference:

```
void foo(auto function_object)
{
    // ref could be reference
    // or a wrapper whose lifetime will be extended
    auto&& ref = function_object(); 

// usage
T& returns_ref();
std::reference_wrapper<T> returns_wrapper();

foo(returns_ref);
foo(returns_wrapper);
```

Comment: Related article:  https://herbsutter.com/2008/01/01/gotw-88-a-candidate-for-the-most-important-const/

Comment: @G.Sliepen I've clarified the answer.

Comment: OP's placement of the `&` has confused everyone :)

Comment: @eerorika `const auto& myOBj_ref = MyClass();` <-- isn't this preferred because it avoids copying a MyClass object since we are only assigning it to a reference?

Comment: @user1008636 No, there is no copy to be avoided.

Comment: @eerorika why not ?

Comment: @user1008636 Because the rules of the language say that there is not (since C++17) or because the rules of the language say that there doesn't need to be (before C++17). In short, prvalues are special. Look up "copy elision".

Answer (score -1):

Edit: see @user17732522 comment about using `const MyClass& myObj = MyClass();`, which might answer question better.

---

I think you have a misunderstanding about references to where an object is initialized:

You can initialize an instance of a class on the heap using the `new` keyword. If you do this, you get a pointer to your object, so you should use `MyClass* myObj = new MyClass()` to initlaize it. You can dereference the pointer yourself, but you must remember to delete the pointer reference later.

Or, you can initialize an instance of a class on the stack, which returns a prvalue (pure value, not reference) to the object. Here you can use `Myclass myObj = MyClass()`, you do not get a pointer but a prvalue to your object.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class MyClass {
    public:
    void printHi() {
        std::cout << "hi";
    }
};

int main()
{
    
    MyClass* myObj = new MyClass();
    myObj->printHi(); // prints Hi
    delete myObj; // don't forget to free objects initialized using `new`
    
    MyClass myObj2 = MyClass();
    myObj2.printHi(); // prints Hi
    
    
    // error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type ‘MyClass&’ from an rvalue of type ‘MyClass*’
    // MyClass& myObj = new MyClass();
    // myObj->printHi(); // does not reach here

    // error: cannot bind non-const lvalue reference of type ‘MyClass&’ to an rvalue of type ‘MyClass’
    //MyClass& myObj = MyClass();
    //myObj->printHi(); // does not reach here

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: my original question had i a type, I meant: MyClass& myObj = MyClass()

Comment: It will compile if you use `auto` here. However, putting the `&` reference operator here does not make sense, syntax wise. You get the error I put in the example if you try to use `MyClass&` .

Comment: What makes you think the question is about pointers instead of references?

Comment: OP did not use `new` at all, and everything they said was related to references. So I'm really unsure as to why you're using `new` and talking about pointers.

Comment: @ChrisMM, why would they try to dereference a reference? OP seems to misunderstand the dereferencing operator, so I was trying to clarify the difference, and explained that using `MyClass& myObj = new MyClass();` returns an error. I added an example for `MyClass& myObj = MyClass();` as well..

Comment: *"`Myclass myObj = MyClass()`, you do not get a pointer but a reference to your object."* - well that's completely wrong. A reference has a very well defined meaning in C++ and that code does not involves references

Comment: @sleepystar96 The question is not talking about dereferencing anything. `MyClass& myObj = MyClass();` is wrong only because it is missing a `const` on the reference's type. `myObj` would be accessed directly as in `myObj.printHi();` (assuming that function was `const` qualified) without any dereferencing.

Comment: @UnholySheep, respectfully, what is assigned to myObj when a class is initialized? Is it not a copy (aka reference) to the newly created object? Asking for my understanding, thank you!

Comment: @user17732522, understood, thanks for explaining.

Comment: Copy and reference are two completely different things in C++. You cannot say *"a copy (aka reference)"*, that is completely wrong. And since C++17 `Myclass myObj = MyClass()` is guaranteed to not involved any copies, it will directly initialize the `myObj` object

Comment: @sleepystar96 A _reference_ in C++ terminology is a _variable_ which has a _reference type_, that is a type qualified with a _ref-qualifier_ (i.e. `&` or `&&`). A _variable_ is specifically an entity introduced by a declaration and is therefore not the same as an _object_. Specifically a _variable_ is declaring either an _object_ or a _reference_. In `Myclass myObj = MyClass();` the name `myObj` is declared to be an object variable, in `Myclass* myObj = new MyClass();` as well, but in `Myclass& myObj = MyClass();` it is declared to be a reference variable.

Comment: Understood, thanks for explaining @UnholySheep!

Comment: In neither case is the expression `MyClass()` a reference or a variable. It is just a prvalue expression of type `MyClass` which may or may not be materialized into a temporary object, but not _variable_, of type `MyClass`. In `const Myclass& myObj = MyClass();` that is what happens and the _reference variable_ binds to the temporary object. In `Myclass myObj = MyClass();` that does not happen, instead the _object variable_ `myObj` is initialized from the prvalue.

Comment: Gotcha, thanks for explaining the specifics regarding WHAT the variable is holding @user17732522!